# Responsive Table on Mobile per CSS only

Tags: html, css

I want to create a normal table on desktop browsers that transforms into a vertical table with some space between the data on a mobile device. The Data should be in height so that the table has not more width than the screen.

Basically, I want to do this with CSS only!

I tried something with CSS and rotate. My Approach with CSS only for rotate.

Now:

```
Col1        Col2
data1_1     data1_2
data2_1     data2_2
```

Should be:

```
Col1 data1_1 
Col2 data1_2
some padding here then second "row"
Col1 data2_1
Col2 data2_2
```

The Table Code:

```js
@media(max - width: 767 px) {
  .table {
    rotate: -90 px;
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Col1</th>
      <th scope="col">Col2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>data1_1</td>
      <td>data1_2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data2_1</td>
      <td>data2_2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `rotate` is not a CSS a property. Search for **css responsive table** on Google, you will find a lot of example, as [this one](https://codepen.io/AllThingsSmitty/pen/MyqmdM).

Comment: Tables and responsive designs are not the best of friends. Your mark up will need to change drastically, CSS can not create a duplicate header (Col1, Col2) as you require from your mobile example.

Answer (score 0):

best i could come up with:

html:

```
<table class="table">
      <thead>
         <tr>
          <th scope="col">Col1</th>
           <th scope="col">Col2</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>data1_1</td>
          <td>data1_2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>data2_1</td>
          <td>data2_2</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

css:

```
.table {
  border:1px solid black;
  margin-top:-2em;
}

.table tr {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  margin-bottom:1.5em;
}

.table thead {
  transform:rotate(90deg) translateX(80%) translateY(-1.75em);
}

.table thead tr {
  flex-direction:row;
}

.table thead tr th {
  padding-left:1em;
}

.table thead tr th:first-child {
  padding-left:0;
}
```

linky:

https://codepen.io/carolmckayau/pen/BqYoBe

Answer (score 0):

best and easy approach concept as below :

```js
window.onload = function () {
  'use strict';

  var i,
    element;

  //create headers for the mobile view
  (function () {
    var headers = document.querySelectorAll("th"),
      index = 1,
      columns = document.querySelectorAll("td"),
      headerName,
      responsiveHeader;

    if (columns.length > 0) {
      for (i = 0; i < columns.length; i += 1) {
        if (index > headers.length) {
          index = 1;
        }
        //mobile headers are actually td
        element = columns[i];
        headerName = document.querySelector('th:nth-of-type(' + index + ')').textContent;
        responsiveHeader = document.createElement("td");

        responsiveHeader.className = "responsive-header";
        responsiveHeader.innerHTML = headerName;
        element.parentNode.insertBefore(responsiveHeader, element);

        index+=1;
      }
    }
  }());

  var tableMinWidth,
    hasBeenSet = false;
 
  //addds mobile class for table when table is larger than screen
  function sytleTable () {
    var tableWidth = document.querySelector('.responsive-table').offsetWidth,
      windowWidth = window.innerWidth,
      responsiveTables = document.getElementsByClassName('responsive-table');

    if (tableWidth >= windowWidth) {
      if (!hasBeenSet) {
        tableMinWidth = tableWidth;
        hasBeenSet = true;
      }

      for (i = 0; i < responsiveTables.length; i += 1) {
        element = responsiveTables[i];
        element.classList.add("mobile");
      }

    } else if (tableWidth >= tableMinWidth) {

      for (i = 0; i < responsiveTables.length ; i += 1) {
        element = responsiveTables[i];
        element.classList.remove("mobile");
      }

    }
  }

  window.onresize = function () {
    sytleTable();
  };

  sytleTable();
}; //window.onload
```

```css
/*Responsive Tables*/

tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}

th {
  font-weight: bold;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 6px;
  text-align: left;
}

.responsive-header {
  display: none;
}


/*Mobile*/

.responsive-table.mobile,
.mobile thead,
.mobile tbody,
.mobile th,
.mobile td,
.mobile tr {
  display: block;
}

.mobile thead tr {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}

.mobile tr {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.mobile td {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.mobile .responsive-header {
  font-size: 18px !important;
  color: #444444 !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px !important;
  padding-left: 5px!important;
  border:none;
  ;
}

.mobile td:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  left: 6px;
  width: 45%;
  padding-right: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//s3.amazonaws.com/libapps/sites/210/include/style.css">
<table class="responsive-table">
   <thead >
   <tr >
     <th>Name</th>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th>Type & #</th>
    <th>Sunday</th>
    <th>Monday</th>
    <th>Tuesday</th>
    <th>Wednesday</th>
    <th>Thursday</th>
    <th>Friday</th>
    <th>Saturday</th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody >
   <tr >
    <td><a href="http://irsc-asc.weebly.com/">Academic Support Center</a><hr>
    <em>Computer Information</em>: Student use only. B&W printing 10c/page. No time limit.
    </td>
     <td>L200</td>
    <td>15 (PC)</td>
    <td>1 p.m. - 5 p.m.</td>
    <td>8 a.m. - 9 p.m.</td>
    <td>8 a.m. - 9 p.m.</td>
    <td>8 a.m. - 9 p.m.</td>
    <td>8 a.m. - 9 p.m.</td>
    <td>8 a.m. - 2 p.m.</td>
    <td>Closed</td>
    
   </tr>
   <tr >
    <td><a href="https://www.irsc.edu/careercenter/careercenter.aspx">Career Center</a><hr>
    <em>Computer Information</em>: Student/Alumni use only. Free B&W   printing (5 page max). Scanner available for student use.
    Software includes WinWay Resume, Microsoft Office. 
    </td>
    <td>W104</td>
    <td>18 (PC)</td>
    <td>Closed</td>
    <td>8 a.m. - 6:30 p.m.</td>
    <td>8 a.m. - 6:30 p.m.</td>
    <td>8 a.m. - 6:30 p.m.</td>
    <td>8 a.m. - 6:30 p.m.</td>
    <td>8 a.m. - 5 p.m.</td>
    <td>Closed</td>
   </tr>
   <tr >
    <td><a href="http://irsc.libguides.com/aboutthelibraries">Miley Library</a><hr>
    <em>Computer Information</em>: Student and community computers available.  time limit for community use.
    B&W printing 10c/page.
    Printing (B&W), research assistance, Microsoft Office.<br>
    For more information, view the 
    <a href="http://irsc.libguides.com/c.php?g=553156&p=3800300">College library guidelines.</a>
    </td>
    </td>
    <td>L100</td>
    <td >24 (PC)</td>
    <td>1 p.m. - 5 p.m.</td>
    <td>7:45 a.m - 9 p.m.</td>
    <td>7:45 a.m - 9 p.m.</td>
    <td>7:45 a.m - 9 p.m.</td>
    <td>7:45 a.m - 9 p.m.</td>
    <td>7:45 a.m - 5 p.m.</td>
    <td>Closed</td>
   </tr>
   <tr >
     <td>Student Services <hr>
     <em>Computer Information</em> Student use only (ID required). B&W printing 10c/page. No time limit.
     B&W Printing is free (5 page limit). 
     </td>
     <td>W103</td>
     <td>33 (PC)</td>
    <td>Closed</td>
    <td>8 a.m. - 6:30 p.m.</td>
    <td>8 a.m. - 6:30 p.m.</td>
    <td>8 a.m. - 6:30 p.m.</td>
    <td>8 a.m. - 6:30 p.m.</td>
    <td>8 a.m. - 5 p.m.</td>
    <td>Closed</td>
   </tr>
   <tr >
     <td>Kight Center Computer Lab <hr>
     <em>Services and information: Services vary. 
     </em>:
     </td>
     <td>V216</td>
    <td>18 (Mac)</td>
    <td>Closed</td>
    <td>10 a.m. - 8 p.m.</td>
    <td>10 a.m. - 8 p.m.</td>
    <td>10 a.m. - 8 p.m.</td>
    <td>10 a.m. - 8 p.m.</td>
    <td>10 a.m. - 8 p.m.</td>
    <td>10 a.m. - 4 p.m.</td>
   </tr>
   <tr >
     <td>Computer Science Labs<hr>
     <em>Services and information</em>: Lab hours and services vary. 
     </td>
     <td>Various</td>
    <td>Various</td>
    <td colspan= 7><center><a href="http://irsccsdept.org/schedule/">Check Lab Schedule</a></center></td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```